# DynamoDb scan Returning all data on Local but not On Live

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I used the recursive calls to get data more then 1 mb data from the dynamodb using this

```
params.ConsistentRead = true;
  let projectCollection = [];
  dynamoDb.scan(params, onQuery);
  function onQuery(err, data) {
      const methodName = 'onQuery';
      if (err) {
          callback(err);
      } else {
          for (let i = 0; i < data.Items.length; i++) {
              projectCollection.push(data.Items[i]);
          }
          if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey !== 'undefined') {
              params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
              dynamoDb.scan(params, onQuery);

          } else {        
              callback(err, projectCollection); //recursive call
          }
      }
  }
};
```

but i get the data on my localhost but once i deployed it on aws ,
where calls pass through the pipeline API GATEWAY then lambda then dynamodb ,my function does not return all the data but a small chunk.

Is it a Cache issue?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, but I think its more likely you are not paging through your Scan results as expected. I think the most likely explanation is you are reading the first page only.

I'm not a nodejs person but I notice you are using a strict operand:

```
typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey !== 'undefined'
```

You seem to be applying a test against a string which I assume will always return true. To be fair I don't think this is your underlying problem, but should you be using..?

```
typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used QUERY instead ,and its giving data faster as per need.

```
let items = [];
  let queryExecute = function(callback) {
      dynamoDb.query(params,function(err,result) {
          if(err) {
              callback(err);
              } else {
              items = items.concat(result.Items);
              if(result.LastEvaluatedKey) {
                  params.ExclusiveStartKey = result.LastEvaluatedKey;
                  queryExecute(callback);
                  } else {         
                      callback(err,items);
                  }
              }
          });
      };
```